# NodeJS no data returned from function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api

I am working on a simple weather application which uses mysql database that has just the names of the cities. Than i query the database for all the names and i send request to openweathermap's API for the weather info.

```
function getCities() {
  con.connect();
  con.query(('SELECT city_name FROM cities'), (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    getWeather(cities);
  });
};

async function getWeather(cities) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    var url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cities[i].city_name}&units=metric&appid=271d1234d3f497eed5b1d80a07b3fcd1`;
    await request(url, (err, res, body) => {
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      var weather = {
        city: json.name,
        temperature: json.main.temp,
        description: json.weather[0].description,
        icon: json.weather[0].icon
      };
      data.push(weather);
    });
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

The `getCities()` function works as expected and returns all the cities but the errors happen in the getWeather function particulary these errors:

```
Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:130
            throw thrownException;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
    at Request.request [as _rp_callbackOrig] (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/app.js:60:41)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:76:39)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/kristijan/Desktop/WeatherApp/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

As far as i understood it is jumping the inside of the arrow function before getting the result from the API ?

Comment: `request` does not return a promise, so your `await` does nothing.  You need to actually use promises.

Comment: Fixed a part of it now it returns the data actually. The only thing now i cannot conclude is when i render the page how can i wait for the return of data first and then render it

Comment: Please indent your code properly (you can fix it with the "edit" link).  It's very hard to read code that is falsely indented.

Comment: You might not want to connect every time someone calls `getCities()` because if that is actually creating the connection to your MySQL instance, that's a very expensive call that could fail sometimes--it would be better to hold the connection as a singleton or just a member variable in the local context

Answer (score 1):

`await` only waits for the async operation if the function result you are awaiting returns a promise.  The `request()` function does not return a promise (it works with the callback you are passing it) and thus `await` does not wait for that result.  You can use the `request-promise` library instead which does return a promise and you do not pass it a callback.

Here's an example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getWeather(cities) {
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cities[i].city_name}&units=metric&appid=271d1234d3f497eed5b1d80a07b3fcd1`;
    let body = await rp(url);
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    let weather = {
        city: json.name,
        temperature: json.main.temp,
        description: json.weather[0].description,
        icon: json.weather[0].icon
    };
    data.push(weather);
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

Note, you can also let the request API parse the JSON for you automatically:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getWeather(cities) {
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cities[i].city_name}&units=metric&appid=271d1234d3f497eed5b1d80a07b3fcd1`;
    let json = await rp({uri:url, json: true});
    let weather = {
        city: json.name,
        temperature: json.main.temp,
        description: json.weather[0].description,
        icon: json.weather[0].icon
    };
    data.push(weather);
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.